# ¿Como quitar el borde negro del pseudo elemento &::-webkit-scrollbar-track?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy personalizando mi `scrollbar` pero por más que intento no he logrado quitar el borde del `scrollbar-track,` me queda un borde negro que no quiero que este, no se si es un borde o una sombra, solo quiero que desaparezca Como hago esto?

Comment: Por favor, muestra tu código para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Si se trata de un borde puedes modificar-lo con la propiedad `border`:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border: 0px none #FFFFFF;
}
```

Si se trata de una sombra puedes usar `box-shadow`

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: none 0 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: no funciona ya lo probe